# How to make Thymeleaf rendering fail when binding failure occurs?

Tags: thymeleaf

In Thymeleaf, when binding failure by absence of a property,

the property is replaced with empty string.

How to make Thymeleaf fail to render in the case?

UPDATE:

This is a sample project I'm working on:

https://github.com/izeye/samples-spring-boot-branches/tree/thymeleaf

When I run the `HomeControllerTests.test()`,

I expect I've got an exception

because I did not provide the `age` property in the model.

But it's rendered with an empty string.

I agree it's a nice behavior in general

but in my current situation,

I hope to be certain that there's no missing property when rendering.

Comment: can you show us your code and what is happening